# Multiple sequence alignment in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, bioinformatics

(The entire project lives [here](https://github.com/coderodde/MultipleSequenceAligner).)

## Problem definition

Suppose we are given three genomic strings drawn from the alphabet of 20 amino acids:

```
ACGH
CFG
EAC
```

In multiple sequence alignment problem we want to align them *optimally* in order to access their evolutionary similarity. Such an alignment may look like the following:

```
-AC-GH
--CFG-
EAC---
```

## Solution

Often, the problem is cast as a pathfinding problem in \$k\$-dimensional lattice, where \$k\$ is the number of strings. Here is my program, it compares A* with Dijkstra's algorithms:

**MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public final class MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance {

    /**
     * The penalty for pairs in which there is one valid character and one gap.
     */
    private final int gapPenalty;

    /**
     * The character pairs cost matrix.
     */
    private final CostMatrix<Integer> costMatrix;

    /**
     * The array of sequences to be aligned.
     */
    private final String[] sequenceArray;

    // A small speed optimization:
    private final char[] column;

    public MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance(CostMatrix<Integer> costMatrix,
                                             int gapPenalty,
                                             String... sequenceArray) {
        this.costMatrix = Objects.requireNonNull(costMatrix,
                                                 "Cost matrix is null");
        this.gapPenalty = gapPenalty;
        this.sequenceArray = sequenceArray.clone();
        this.column = new char[sequenceArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i != sequenceArray.length; ++i) {
            this.sequenceArray[i] = 
                    checkIsValidGenomicSequence(sequenceArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public Alignment align() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HeuristicFunction hf = new HeuristicFunctionComputer()
                .computeHeuristicFunction(this);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Computed heuristic function in " + (end - start) +
                           " milliseconds.");

        Queue<LatticeNodeHolder> open = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Map<LatticeNode, Integer> distance = new HashMap<>();
        Map<LatticeNode, LatticeNode> parents = new HashMap<>();

        LatticeNode sourceNode = getSourceNode();
        LatticeNode targetNode = getTargetNode();

        open.add(new LatticeNodeHolder(sourceNode, 0));
        distance.put(sourceNode, 0);
        parents.put(sourceNode, null);

        Set<LatticeNode> closed = new HashSet<>();

        while (true) {
            LatticeNode currentNode = open.remove().getNode();

            if (currentNode.equals(targetNode)) {
                return tracebackPath(parents, distance.get(currentNode));
            }

            if (closed.contains(currentNode)) {
                continue;
            }

            closed.add(currentNode);

            for (LatticeNode childNode : currentNode.getChildren()) {
                if (closed.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                int tentativeCost = distance.get(currentNode) +
                                    getWeight(currentNode, childNode);
                Integer currentCost = distance.get(childNode);

                if (currentCost == null || currentCost > tentativeCost) {
                    open.add(new LatticeNodeHolder(childNode, 
                                                   tentativeCost + 
                                                           hf.get(childNode)));
                    distance.put(childNode, tentativeCost);
                    parents.put(childNode, currentNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Alignment alignBrute() {
        Queue<LatticeNodeHolder> open = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Map<LatticeNode, Integer> distance = new HashMap<>();
        Map<LatticeNode, LatticeNode> parents = new HashMap<>();

        LatticeNode sourceNode = getSourceNode();
        LatticeNode targetNode = getTargetNode();

        open.add(new LatticeNodeHolder(sourceNode, 0));
        distance.put(sourceNode, 0);
        parents.put(sourceNode, null);

        Set<LatticeNode> closed = new HashSet<>();

        while (true) {
            LatticeNode currentNode = open.remove().getNode();

            if (currentNode.equals(targetNode)) {
                return tracebackPath(parents, distance.get(currentNode));
            }

            if (closed.contains(currentNode)) {
                continue;
            }

            closed.add(currentNode);

            for (LatticeNode childNode : currentNode.getChildren()) {
                if (closed.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                int tentativeCost = distance.get(currentNode) +
                                    getWeight(currentNode, childNode);
                Integer currentCost = distance.get(childNode);

                if (currentCost == null || currentCost > tentativeCost) {
                    open.add(new LatticeNodeHolder(childNode, tentativeCost));
                    distance.put(childNode, tentativeCost);
                    parents.put(childNode, currentNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the source node for the sequence alignment task, i.e., a lattice 
     * node with all coordinates set to zero.
     * 
     * @return the source node.
     */
    LatticeNode getSourceNode() {
        int[] sourceCoordinates = new int[sequenceArray.length];
        return new LatticeNode(this, sourceCoordinates);
    }

    /**
     * Create the target node for the sequence alignment task, i.e., a lattice
     * node with all coordinates set to the respective sequence lengths.
     * 
     * @return the target node.
     */
    LatticeNode getTargetNode() {
        int[] targetCoordinates = new int[sequenceArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i != sequenceArray.length; ++i) {
            targetCoordinates[i] = sequenceArray[i].length();
        }

        return new LatticeNode(this, targetCoordinates);
    }

    Integer getWeight(LatticeNode tail,
                      LatticeNode head, 
                      int dimension1,
                      int dimension2) {
        int[] tailCoordinates = tail.getCoordinates();
        int[] headCoordinates = head.getCoordinates();

        if (tailCoordinates[dimension1] == headCoordinates[dimension1]) {
            //System.out.println("1");
            return gapPenalty;
        } else if (tailCoordinates[dimension2] == headCoordinates[dimension2]) {
            //System.out.println("2");
            return gapPenalty;
        } else {
//            System.out.println("3");
            char character1 = sequenceArray[dimension1]
                    .charAt(tailCoordinates[dimension1]);

            char character2 = sequenceArray[dimension2]
                    .charAt(tailCoordinates[dimension2]);
            return costMatrix.getCost(character1, character2);
        }
    }

    Integer getWeight(LatticeNode tail, LatticeNode head) {
        // Extract the column represented by taking a single hop from 'tail' to
        // 'head':
        int[] tailCoordinates = tail.getCoordinates();
        int[] headCoordinates = head.getCoordinates();

        for (int i = 0; i < sequenceArray.length; ++i) {
            if (tailCoordinates[i] + 1 == headCoordinates[i]) {
                column[i] = sequenceArray[i].charAt(tailCoordinates[i]);
            } else {
                column[i] = AminoAcidAlphabet.GAP_CHARACTER;
            }
        }

        // Compute the hop cost as the sum of pairwise hops in any plane:
        int cost = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < column.length; ++i) {
            char character1 = column[i];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < column.length; ++j) {
                char character2 = column[j];

                if (character1 != AminoAcidAlphabet.GAP_CHARACTER) {
                    if (character2 != AminoAcidAlphabet.GAP_CHARACTER) {
                        cost += costMatrix.getCost(character1, character2);
                    } else {
                        cost += gapPenalty;
                    }
                } else {
                    // character1 IS the gap character:
                    if (character2 != AminoAcidAlphabet.GAP_CHARACTER) {
                        cost += gapPenalty;
                    } else {
                        // Do nothing since we have a pair (gap, gap).
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return cost;
    }

    String[] getSequenceArray() {
        return sequenceArray;
    }

    private Alignment tracebackPath(Map<LatticeNode, LatticeNode> parents,
                                    Integer cost) {
        List<LatticeNode> path = new ArrayList<>();
        LatticeNode node = getTargetNode();

        while (node != null) {
            path.add(node);
            node = parents.get(node);
        }

        Collections.<LatticeNode>reverse(path);

        String[] strings = new String[getSequenceArray().length];
        StringBuilder[] stringBuilders = new StringBuilder[strings.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringBuilders.length; ++i) {
            stringBuilders[i] = new StringBuilder();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < path.size(); ++i) {
            LatticeNode tail = path.get(i - 1);
            LatticeNode head = path.get(i);

            int[] tailCoordinates = tail.getCoordinates();
            int[] headCoordinates = head.getCoordinates();

            for (int j = 0; j < tailCoordinates.length; ++j) {
                if (tailCoordinates[j] != headCoordinates[j]) {
                    stringBuilders[j].
                            append(sequenceArray[j].charAt(tailCoordinates[j]));
                } else {
                    stringBuilders[j].append(AminoAcidAlphabet.GAP_CHARACTER);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
            strings[i] = stringBuilders[i].toString();
        }

        return new Alignment(strings, cost);
    }

    private String checkIsValidGenomicSequence(String string) {
        Set<Character> characterSet = 
                AminoAcidAlphabet.getAminoAcidAlphabet()
                                 .getCharacterSet();

        for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
            if (!characterSet.contains(c)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown amino acid: " + c);
            }
        }

        return string;
    }

    private static final class LatticeNodeHolder
            implements Comparable<LatticeNodeHolder> {

        private final Integer fScore;
        private final LatticeNode node;

        LatticeNodeHolder(LatticeNode node, Integer fScore) {
            this.fScore = fScore;
            this.node = node;
        }

        LatticeNode getNode() {
            return node;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(LatticeNodeHolder o) {
            return Integer.compare(fScore, o.fScore);
        }
    }
}
```

**HeuristicFunctionComputer.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

final class HeuristicFunctionComputer {

    HeuristicFunction computeHeuristicFunction(
            MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance instance) {
        String[] sequenceArray = instance.getSequenceArray();
        HeuristicFunction heuristicFunction = new HeuristicFunction(instance);

        for (int dimension1 = 0; 
                dimension1 < sequenceArray.length; 
                dimension1++) {
            for (int dimension2 = dimension1 + 1; 
                    dimension2 < sequenceArray.length; 
                    dimension2++) {
                loadPartialHeuristicFunction(heuristicFunction,
                                             dimension1,
                                             dimension2,
                                             instance);
            }
        }

        return heuristicFunction;
    }

    // Basically, this method runs Dijkstra backwards from the target node until
    // the entire 2D-grid is explored.
    private void loadPartialHeuristicFunction(
            HeuristicFunction heuristicFunction,
            int dimension1,
            int dimension2,
            MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance instance) {
        LatticeNode target = instance.getTargetNode();
        Queue<LatticeNodeHolder> open = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<LatticeNode> closed = new HashSet<>();
        open.add(new LatticeNodeHolder(target, 0));
        Point point = new Point();

        while (!open.isEmpty()) {
            LatticeNodeHolder currentNodeHolder = open.remove();
            LatticeNode currentNode = currentNodeHolder.getLatticeNode();

            if (closed.contains(currentNode)) {
                continue;
            }

            closed.add(currentNode);

            Integer currentNodeCost = currentNodeHolder.getCost();
            extractPoint(point, currentNode, dimension1, dimension2);
            heuristicFunction.put(dimension1,
                                  dimension2, 
                                  new Point(point),
                                  currentNodeCost);

            for (LatticeNode parent : currentNode.getParents()) {
                if (closed.contains(parent)) {
                    continue;
                }

                int tentativeCost =
                        currentNodeCost + instance.getWeight(parent, 
                                                             currentNode, 
                                                             dimension1, 
                                                             dimension2);
                extractPoint(point, parent, dimension1, dimension2);

                if (!heuristicFunction.containsPartial(dimension1,
                                                       dimension2, 
                                                       point)
                        || heuristicFunction.getPartial(dimension1,
                                                        dimension2,
                                                        point)
                        > tentativeCost) {
                    open.add(new LatticeNodeHolder(parent, tentativeCost));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void extractPoint(Point point,
                                     LatticeNode latticeNode, 
                                     int i, 
                                     int j) {
        int[] coordinates = latticeNode.getCoordinates();
        point.x = coordinates[i];
        point.y = coordinates[j];
    }

    private static final class LatticeNodeHolder 
         implements Comparable<LatticeNodeHolder> {

        private final LatticeNode node;
        private final Integer cost;

        LatticeNodeHolder(LatticeNode node, Integer cost) {
            this.node = node;
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        LatticeNode getLatticeNode() {
            return node;
        }

        Integer getCost() {
            return cost;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(LatticeNodeHolder o) {
            return Integer.compare(cost, o.cost);
        }
    }
}
```

**LatticeNode.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

import com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.OperationFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;

final class LatticeNode {

    /**
     * The problem instance this lattice node contributes to.
     */
    private final MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance instance;

    /**
     * The coordinates of this node in the entire lattice.
     */
    private final int[] coordinates;

    LatticeNode(MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance instance, int[] coordinates) {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return Arrays.equals(coordinates, ((LatticeNode) o).coordinates);
    }

    // Generated by NetBeans 8.1:
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 41 * hash + Arrays.hashCode(this.coordinates);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        String separator = "";

        for (int coordinate : coordinates) {
            sb.append(separator).append(coordinate);
            separator = ", ";
        }

        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    LatticeNode[] getChildren() {
        // Find out in how many dimension we can move forward:
        int dimensionsNotReached = 0;
        String[] sequenceArray = instance.getSequenceArray();
        boolean[] inclusionMap = new boolean[coordinates.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sequenceArray.length; ++i) {
            if (coordinates[i] < sequenceArray[i].length()) {
                dimensionsNotReached++;
                // We can make a step forward in the direction of ith dimension:
                inclusionMap[i] = true;
            }
        }

        // Create the array of children:
        int numberOfChildren = pow2(dimensionsNotReached) - 1;
        LatticeNode[] children = new LatticeNode[numberOfChildren];
        loadChildren(children, inclusionMap);

        // Convert offsets to actual child coordinates:
        for (LatticeNode child : children) {
            child.addOffsets(coordinates);
        }

        return children;
    }

    LatticeNode[] getParents() {
        // Find out in how many dimensions we can move BACKward:
        int dimensionsNotReached = 0;
        String[] sequenceArray = instance.getSequenceArray();
        boolean[] inclusionMap = new boolean[coordinates.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sequenceArray.length; ++i) {
            if (coordinates[i] > 0) {
                dimensionsNotReached++;
                // We can make a step backwards in the direction of ith 
                // dimension:
                inclusionMap[i] = true;
            }
        }

        // Create the array of parents:
        int numberOfParents = pow2(dimensionsNotReached) - 1;
        LatticeNode[] parents = new LatticeNode[numberOfParents];
        loadParents(parents, inclusionMap);

        // Convert the offsets to actual parent coordinates:
        for (LatticeNode parent : parents) {
            parent.addOffsets(coordinates);
        }

        return parents;
    }

    int[] getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    private void loadChildren(LatticeNode[] children, boolean[] inclusionMap) {
        int[] coords = new int[this.coordinates.length];

        for (int i = 0; i != children.length; ++i) {
            increment(coords, inclusionMap);
            children[i] = new LatticeNode(instance, coords.clone());
        }
    }

    private void loadParents(LatticeNode[] parents, boolean[] inclusionMap) {
        int[] coords = new int[this.coordinates.length];

        for (int i = 0; i != parents.length; ++i) {
            decrement(coords, inclusionMap);
            parents[i] = new LatticeNode(instance, coords.clone());
        }
    }

    private static void increment(int[] coordinates, boolean[] inclusionMap) {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; ++i) {
            if (!inclusionMap[i]) {
                continue;
            }

            if (coordinates[i] == 0) {
                coordinates[i] = 1;
                return;
            }

            coordinates[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    private static void decrement(int[] coordinates, boolean[] inclusionMap) {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; ++i) {
            if (!inclusionMap[i]) {
                continue;
            }

            if (coordinates[i] == 0) {
                coordinates[i] = -1;
                return;
            }

            coordinates[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    private void addOffsets(int[] offsets) {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; ++i) {
            coordinates[i] += offsets[i];
        }
    }

    private static int pow2(int exponent) {
        int ret = 1;

        for (int e = 0; e < exponent; ++e) {
            ret *= 2;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

**PAM250CostMatrix.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import net.coderodde.bio.msa.AminoAcidAlphabet;
import net.coderodde.bio.msa.CostMatrix;

public final class PAM250CostMatrix implements CostMatrix<Integer> {

    private static PAM250CostMatrix instance;

    private final Map<Character, Map<Character, Integer>> m = new HashMap<>();

    public static PAM250CostMatrix getPAM250CostMatrix() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PAM250CostMatrix();
        }

        return instance;
    } 

    private PAM250CostMatrix() {
        AminoAcidAlphabet alphabet = AminoAcidAlphabet.getAminoAcidAlphabet();

        alphabet.getCharacterSet().stream().forEach((character) -> {
            m.put(character, new HashMap<>());
        });

        m.get('A').put('A', -2);
        m.get('R').put('A', 2);
        m.get('A').put('R', 2);
        m.get('R').put('R', -6);
        m.get('N').put('A', 0);
        m.get('A').put('N', 0);
        m.get('N').put('R', 0);
        m.get('R').put('N', 0);
        m.get('N').put('N', -2);
        m.get('D').put('A', 0);
        m.get('A').put('D', 0);
        m.get('D').put('R', 1);
        m.get('R').put('D', 1);
        m.get('D').put('N', -2);
        m.get('N').put('D', -2);
        m.get('D').put('D', -4);
        m.get('C').put('A', 2);
        m.get('A').put('C', 2);
        m.get('C').put('R', 4);
        m.get('R').put('C', 4);
        m.get('C').put('N', 4);
        m.get('N').put('C', 4);
        m.get('C').put('D', 5);
        m.get('D').put('C', 5);
        m.get('C').put('C', -4);
        m.get('Q').put('A', 0);
        m.get('A').put('Q', 0);
        m.get('Q').put('R', -1);
        m.get('R').put('Q', -1);
        m.get('Q').put('N', -1);
        m.get('N').put('Q', -1);
        m.get('Q').put('D', -2);
        m.get('D').put('Q', -2);
        m.get('Q').put('C', 5);
        m.get('C').put('Q', 5);
        m.get('Q').put('Q', -4);
        m.get('E').put('A', 0);
        m.get('A').put('E', 0);
        m.get('E').put('R', 1);
        m.get('R').put('E', 1);
        m.get('E').put('N', -1);
        m.get('N').put('E', -1);
        m.get('E').put('D', -3);
        m.get('D').put('E', -3);
        m.get('E').put('C', 5);
        m.get('C').put('E', 5);
        m.get('E').put('Q', -2);
        m.get('Q').put('E', -2);
        m.get('E').put('E', -4);
        m.get('G').put('A', -1);
        m.get('A').put('G', -1);
        m.get('G').put('R', 3);
        m.get('R').put('G', 3);
        m.get('G').put('N', 0);
        m.get('N').put('G', 0);
        m.get('G').put('D', -1);
        m.get('D').put('G', -1);
        m.get('G').put('C', 3);
        m.get('C').put('G', 3);
        m.get('G').put('Q', 1);
        m.get('Q').put('G', 1);
        m.get('G').put('E', 0);
        m.get('E').put('G', 0);
        m.get('G').put('G', -5);
        m.get('H').put('A', 1);
        m.get('A').put('H', 1);
        m.get('H').put('R', -2);
        m.get('R').put('H', -2);
        m.get('H').put('N', -2);
        m.get('N').put('H', -2);
        m.get('H').put('D', -1);
        m.get('D').put('H', -1);
        m.get('H').put('C', 3);
        m.get('C').put('H', 3);
        m.get('H').put('Q', -3);
        m.get('Q').put('H', -3);
        m.get('H').put('E', -1);
        m.get('E').put('H', -1);
        m.get('H').put('G', 2);
        m.get('G').put('H', 2);
        m.get('H').put('H', -6);
        m.get('I').put('A', 1);
        m.get('A').put('I', 1);
        m.get('I').put('R', 2);
        m.get('R').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('N', 2);
        m.get('N').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('D', 2);
        m.get('D').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('C', 2);
        m.get('C').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('Q', 2);
        m.get('Q').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('E', 2);
        m.get('E').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('G', 3);
        m.get('G').put('I', 3);
        m.get('I').put('H', 2);
        m.get('H').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('I', -5);
        m.get('L').put('A', 2);
        m.get('A').put('L', 2);
        m.get('L').put('R', 3);
        m.get('R').put('L', 3);
        m.get('L').put('N', 3);
        m.get('N').put('L', 3);
        m.get('L').put('D', 4);
        m.get('D').put('L', 4);
        m.get('L').put('C', 6);
        m.get('C').put('L', 6);
        m.get('L').put('Q', 2);
        m.get('Q').put('L', 2);
        m.get('L').put('E', 3);
        m.get('E').put('L', 3);
        m.get('L').put('G', 4);
        m.get('G').put('L', 4);
        m.get('L').put('H', 2);
        m.get('H').put('L', 2);
        m.get('L').put('I', -2);
        m.get('I').put('L', -2);
        m.get('L').put('L', -6);
        m.get('K').put('A', 1);
        m.get('A').put('K', 1);
        m.get('K').put('R', -3);
        m.get('R').put('K', -3);
        m.get('K').put('N', -1);
        m.get('N').put('K', -1);
        m.get('K').put('D', 0);
        m.get('D').put('K', 0);
        m.get('K').put('C', 5);
        m.get('C').put('K', 5);
        m.get('K').put('Q', -1);
        m.get('Q').put('K', -1);
        m.get('K').put('E', 0);
        m.get('E').put('K', 0);
        m.get('K').put('G', 2);
        m.get('G').put('K', 2);
        m.get('K').put('H', 0);
        m.get('H').put('K', 0);
        m.get('K').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('K', 2);
        m.get('K').put('L', 3);
        m.get('L').put('K', 3);
        m.get('K').put('K', -5);
        m.get('M').put('A', 1);
        m.get('A').put('M', 1);
        m.get('M').put('R', 0);
        m.get('R').put('M', 0);
        m.get('M').put('N', 2);
        m.get('N').put('M', 2);
        m.get('M').put('D', 3);
        m.get('D').put('M', 3);
        m.get('M').put('C', 5);
        m.get('C').put('M', 5);
        m.get('M').put('Q', 1);
        m.get('Q').put('M', 1);
        m.get('M').put('E', 2);
        m.get('E').put('M', 2);
        m.get('M').put('G', 3);
        m.get('G').put('M', 3);
        m.get('M').put('H', 2);
        m.get('H').put('M', 2);
        m.get('M').put('I', -2);
        m.get('I').put('M', -2);
        m.get('M').put('L', -4);
        m.get('L').put('M', -4);
        m.get('M').put('K', 0);
        m.get('K').put('M', 0);
        m.get('M').put('M', -6);
        m.get('F').put('A', 4);
        m.get('A').put('F', 4);
        m.get('F').put('R', 4);
        m.get('R').put('F', 4);
        m.get('F').put('N', 4);
        m.get('N').put('F', 4);
        m.get('F').put('D', 6);
        m.get('D').put('F', 6);
        m.get('F').put('C', 4);
        m.get('C').put('F', 4);
        m.get('F').put('Q', 5);
        m.get('Q').put('F', 5);
        m.get('F').put('E', 5);
        m.get('E').put('F', 5);
        m.get('F').put('G', 5);
        m.get('G').put('F', 5);
        m.get('F').put('H', 2);
        m.get('H').put('F', 2);
        m.get('F').put('I', -1);
        m.get('I').put('F', -1);
        m.get('F').put('L', -2);
        m.get('L').put('F', -2);
        m.get('F').put('K', 5);
        m.get('K').put('F', 5);
        m.get('F').put('M', 0);
        m.get('M').put('F', 0);
        m.get('F').put('F', -9);
        m.get('P').put('A', -1);
        m.get('A').put('P', -1);
        m.get('P').put('R', 0);
        m.get('R').put('P', 0);
        m.get('P').put('N', 1);
        m.get('N').put('P', 1);
        m.get('P').put('D', 1);
        m.get('D').put('P', 1);
        m.get('P').put('C', 3);
        m.get('C').put('P', 3);
        m.get('P').put('Q', 0);
        m.get('Q').put('P', 0);
        m.get('P').put('E', 1);
        m.get('E').put('P', 1);
        m.get('P').put('G', 1);
        m.get('G').put('P', 1);
        m.get('P').put('H', 0);
        m.get('H').put('P', 0);
        m.get('P').put('I', 2);
        m.get('I').put('P', 2);
        m.get('P').put('L', 3);
        m.get('L').put('P', 3);
        m.get('P').put('K', 1);
        m.get('K').put('P', 1);
        m.get('P').put('M', 2);
        m.get('M').put('P', 2);
        m.get('P').put('F', 5);
        m.get('F').put('P', 5);
        m.get('P').put('P', -6);
        m.get('S').put('A', -1);
        m.get('A').put('S', -1);
        m.get('S').put('R', 0);
        m.get('R').put('S', 0);
        m.get('S').put('N', -1);
        m.get('N').put('S', -1);
        m.get('S').put('D', 0);
        m.get('D').put('S', 0);
        m.get('S').put('C', 0);
        m.get('C').put('S', 0);
        m.get('S').put('Q', 1);
        m.get('Q').put('S', 1);
        m.get('S').put('E', 0);
        m.get('E').put('S', 0);
        m.get('S').put('G', -1);
        m.get('G').put('S', -1);
        m.get('S').put('H', 1);
        m.get('H').put('S', 1);
        m.get('S').put('I', 1);
        m.get('I').put('S', 1);
        m.get('S').put('L', 3);
        m.get('L').put('S', 3);
        m.get('S').put('K', 0);
        m.get('K').put('S', 0);
        m.get('S').put('M', 2);
        m.get('M').put('S', 2);
        m.get('S').put('F', 3);
        m.get('F').put('S', 3);
        m.get('S').put('P', -1);
        m.get('P').put('S', -1);
        m.get('S').put('S', -3);
        m.get('T').put('A', -1);
        m.get('A').put('T', -1);
        m.get('T').put('R', 1);
        m.get('R').put('T', 1);
        m.get('T').put('N', 0);
        m.get('N').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('D', 0);
        m.get('D').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('C', 2);
        m.get('C').put('T', 2);
        m.get('T').put('Q', 1);
        m.get('Q').put('T', 1);
        m.get('T').put('E', 0);
        m.get('E').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('G', 0);
        m.get('G').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('H', 1);
        m.get('H').put('T', 1);
        m.get('T').put('I', 0);
        m.get('I').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('L', 2);
        m.get('L').put('T', 2);
        m.get('T').put('K', 0);
        m.get('K').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('M', 1);
        m.get('M').put('T', 1);
        m.get('T').put('F', 2);
        m.get('F').put('T', 2);
        m.get('T').put('P', 0);
        m.get('P').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('S', -1);
        m.get('S').put('T', -1);
        m.get('T').put('T', -3);
        m.get('W').put('A', 6);
        m.get('A').put('W', 6);
        m.get('W').put('R', -2);
        m.get('R').put('W', -2);
        m.get('W').put('N', 4);
        m.get('N').put('W', 4);
        m.get('W').put('D', 7);
        m.get('D').put('W', 7);
        m.get('W').put('C', 8);
        m.get('C').put('W', 8);
        m.get('W').put('Q', 5);
        m.get('Q').put('W', 5);
        m.get('W').put('E', 7);
        m.get('E').put('W', 7);
        m.get('W').put('G', 7);
        m.get('G').put('W', 7);
        m.get('W').put('H', 3);
        m.get('H').put('W', 3);
        m.get('W').put('I', 5);
        m.get('I').put('W', 5);
        m.get('W').put('L', 2);
        m.get('L').put('W', 2);
        m.get('W').put('K', 3);
        m.get('K').put('W', 3);
        m.get('W').put('M', 4);
        m.get('M').put('W', 4);
        m.get('W').put('F', 0);
        m.get('F').put('W', 0);
        m.get('W').put('P', 6);
        m.get('P').put('W', 6);
        m.get('W').put('S', 2);
        m.get('S').put('W', 2);
        m.get('W').put('T', 5);
        m.get('T').put('W', 5);
        m.get('W').put('W', -17);
        m.get('Y').put('A', 3);
        m.get('A').put('Y', 3);
        m.get('Y').put('R', 4);
        m.get('R').put('Y', 4);
        m.get('Y').put('N', 2);
        m.get('N').put('Y', 2);
        m.get('Y').put('D', 4);
        m.get('D').put('Y', 4);
        m.get('Y').put('C', 0);
        m.get('C').put('Y', 0);
        m.get('Y').put('Q', 4);
        m.get('Q').put('Y', 4);
        m.get('Y').put('E', 4);
        m.get('E').put('Y', 4);
        m.get('Y').put('G', 5);
        m.get('G').put('Y', 5);
        m.get('Y').put('H', 0);
        m.get('H').put('Y', 0);
        m.get('Y').put('I', 1);
        m.get('I').put('Y', 1);
        m.get('Y').put('L', 1);
        m.get('L').put('Y', 1);
        m.get('Y').put('K', 4);
        m.get('K').put('Y', 4);
        m.get('Y').put('M', 2);
        m.get('M').put('Y', 2);
        m.get('Y').put('F', -7);
        m.get('F').put('Y', -7);
        m.get('Y').put('P', 5);
        m.get('P').put('Y', 5);
        m.get('Y').put('S', 3);
        m.get('S').put('Y', 3);
        m.get('Y').put('T', 3);
        m.get('T').put('Y', 3);
        m.get('Y').put('W', 0);
        m.get('W').put('Y', 0);
        m.get('Y').put('Y', -10);
        m.get('V').put('A', 0);
        m.get('A').put('V', 0);
        m.get('V').put('R', 2);
        m.get('R').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('N', 2);
        m.get('N').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('D', 2);
        m.get('D').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('C', 2);
        m.get('C').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('Q', 2);
        m.get('Q').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('E', 2);
        m.get('E').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('G', 1);
        m.get('G').put('V', 1);
        m.get('V').put('H', 2);
        m.get('H').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('I', -4);
        m.get('I').put('V', -4);
        m.get('V').put('L', -2);
        m.get('L').put('V', -2);
        m.get('V').put('K', 2);
        m.get('K').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('M', -2);
        m.get('M').put('V', -2);
        m.get('V').put('F', 1);
        m.get('F').put('V', 1);
        m.get('V').put('P', 1);
        m.get('P').put('V', 1);
        m.get('V').put('S', 1);
        m.get('S').put('V', 1);
        m.get('V').put('T', 0);
        m.get('T').put('V', 0);
        m.get('V').put('W', 6);
        m.get('W').put('V', 6);
        m.get('V').put('Y', 2);
        m.get('Y').put('V', 2);
        m.get('V').put('V', -4);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getCost(Character aminoAcidChar1, Character aminoAcidChar2) {
        try {
            return m.get(aminoAcidChar1).get(aminoAcidChar2);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad arguments: (" +
                    aminoAcidChar1 + ", " + aminoAcidChar2 + ")",
                    ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**AminoAcidAlphabet.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public final class AminoAcidAlphabet {

    public static final Character GAP_CHARACTER = '-';
    private static AminoAcidAlphabet instance;

    private final Set<Character> alphabet = new HashSet<>();

    public static AminoAcidAlphabet getAminoAcidAlphabet() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AminoAcidAlphabet();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private AminoAcidAlphabet() {
        String aminoAcids = "ACDEF" +
                            "GHIKL" +
                            "MNPQR" +
                            "STVWY";

        for (char c : aminoAcids.toCharArray()) {
            alphabet.add(c);
        }
    }

    public Set<Character> getCharacterSet() {
        return Collections.<Character>unmodifiableSet(alphabet);
    }
}
```

**Alignment.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

public class Alignment {

    private final String[] alignment;
    private final int cost;

    Alignment(String[] alignment, int cost) {
        this.alignment = alignment;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String[] getAlignemnt() {
        return alignment;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = "";

        for (String row : alignment) {
            sb.append(separator).append(row);
            separator = "\n";
        }

        sb.append("\nCost: ").append(cost);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**CostMatrix.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

public interface CostMatrix<C> {

    public C getCost(Character aminoAcidChar1, Character aminoAcidChar2);
}
```

**HeuristicFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

final class HeuristicFunction {

    private final Map<Point, Integer>[][] matrix;

    HeuristicFunction(MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance instance) {
        int sequences = instance.getSequenceArray().length;
        this.matrix = new Map[sequences][];

        for (int i = 0; i < sequences; ++i) {
            this.matrix[i] = new Map[sequences];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < sequences; ++j) {
                this.matrix[i][j] = new HashMap<>();
            }
        }
    }

    void put(int dimension1, int dimension2, Point point, Integer cost) {
        matrix[dimension1][dimension2].put(point, cost);
    }

    boolean containsPartial(int dimension1, int dimension2, Point point) {
        return matrix[dimension1][dimension2].containsKey(point);
    }

    Integer getPartial(int dimension1, int dimension2, Point point) {
        return matrix[dimension1][dimension2].get(point);
    }

    Integer get(LatticeNode node) {
        int cost = 0;
        int[] coordinates = node.getCoordinates();
        Point point = new Point();

        for (int dimension1 = 0; 
                dimension1 < coordinates.length; 
                dimension1++) {
            point.x = dimension1;

            for (int dimension2 = dimension1 + 1;
                    dimension2 < coordinates.length; 
                    dimension2++) {
                point.y = dimension2;
                cost += matrix[dimension1][dimension2].get(point);
            }
        }

        return cost;
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
package net.coderodde.bio.msa;

final class App {

    private static final String[] SEQUENCES = {
        "ACGHKGMNPFQEKKFKLMNRW",
        "CFGPQWYRTLMEKKFKNR",
        "EACLMNRPQWTR",
        "TIMWAYHTMGIEKKFK"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance instance = 
                new MultipleSequenceAlignmentInstance(
                        PAM250CostMatrix.getPAM250CostMatrix(),
                        4, 
                        SEQUENCES);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Alignment alignment1 = instance.align();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(alignment1);
        System.out.println(end - start + " ms.");
        System.out.println();

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Alignment alignment2 = instance.alignBrute();
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(alignment2);
        System.out.println(end - start + " ms.");
    }
}
```

**Output**

The output for the demo is

> ```
> Computed heuristic function in 1003 milliseconds.
> -ACG-HKGMNPF-QEKKFKLMNRW
> -CFGPQW-YRTL-MEKKFK--NR-
> EAC--LM-NRP--Q-WT-R-----
> -TI--MWAYHTMGIEKKFK-----
> Cost: 53
> 1126 ms.
>
> -ACG-HKGMNPF-QEKKFKLMNRW
> -CFGPQW-YRTL-MEKKFK--NR-
> EAC--LM-NRP--Q-WT-R-----
> -TI--MWAYHTMGIEKKFK-----
> Cost: 53
> 60 ms.
> ```

## Critique request

As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AminoAcidAlphabet`:

- `getCharacterSet` always return same set, but you always create new instance.

In `PAM250CostMatrix`

- in constructor you can extract method to write `add('A', 'A', -2)` instead of `m.get('A').put('A', -2)`

In `LatticeNode`

- you can make `hashCode` simply do `return Arrays.hashCode(this.coordinates);`